# Localization of images in Assets.xcassets XCode 11 not working

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, localization

I have turned localization on for several image assets in the Assets.xcassets but they aren't getting picked up.

I'm using XCode 11.2.1

All other localizations are working (Localizable.strings, Storyboard localizations). The images are pulled in the storyboards (Could that be the problem? Although the Storyboards that use those assets are also localized).

Thanks!
Jennie

Comment: Run into this issue as well. Xcode picks up just the universal assets and not the localized versions. Neat solution below. Did you find any other options?

Comment: This is still the case for me in Xcode 12.4, but only in the simulator — it works fine on device.

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to fix this, my work around was to name the image file in my `Localizable.strings` files and reference it in code for an image name of

```
let imageName = NSLocalizedString("imageName", tableName: nil, bundle: Bundle.main, value: "", comment: "")
myImageView.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
```